# How to share multiple selected values from the UITableview row to facebook or googledoc?

Tags: iphone

Ha ii everybody i have a Bible application which the user can create notes and Sync it with googledoc.i done every coding for that and i tested the sample note in a textview and pass the value from the textview for upload and it succeed,but my requirement is that i want to get the values from the tableview cell instead of textview,and also i have a multiple select tableview using checkmark and i want to sync if the user select the multiple selection of row .my code for this is

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [appDelegate.indexArray count];
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}
-(UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryTypesForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *CellIdentifier;
    CellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %d",indexPath.row];


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgCELL3@2X-1"]];
        [cell setBackgroundView:img];
        [img release];
        count++;
    }

    NSMutableString *str=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:[appDelegate.indexArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    cell.textLabel.text =str ; 
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:14.0]; 
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];

    NSMutableString *notes=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:[appDelegate.notesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text =notes;
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:14.0]; 
     cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        [notes release];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}
```

The above code is foe UITableview cell

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSArray* toReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: indexPath, self.selectedIndexPath, nil];
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){

        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }

    else {

        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    }

}
```

the above is selection code

```
- (IBAction)doUpload:(id)sender
{
    UploadView *uploadview = (UploadView *)self.view;
    if (uploadview != nil)
    {
        [m_owner uploadString:@""];
        //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

}
```

this is upload button code and i want to pass the multiple or single value from the uitableview in `[m_owner uploadString:here i want to pass the value];`

EDIT:

```
- (IBAction)doUpload:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableArray *rowsToBeDeleted = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int index = 0;


    for (NSNumber *rowSelected in appDelegate.notesArray)
    {
        if ([rowSelected boolValue])
        {

            [rowsToBeDeleted addObject:[appDelegate.notesArray objectAtIndex:index]];
            NSUInteger pathSource[2] = {0, index};
            NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:pathSource length:2];

            [indexPaths addObject:path];
            UploadView *uploadview = (UploadView *)self.view;
            if (uploadview != nil)
            {
                [m_owner uploadString:path];
                //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            }


        }       
        index++;




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (inPseudoEditMode)
    {   
    BOOL selected = [[selectedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] boolValue];
    [selectedArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row] withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!selected]];
    [self.m_PTableView reloadData];
    }

}
```

The array named selectedArray will contain the index of selected cells in UITableView.

```
NSMutableArray *rowsToBeDeleted = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int index = 0;


for (NSNumber *rowSelected in selectedArray)
{
    if ([rowSelected boolValue])
    {

        [rowsToBeDeleted addObject:[rootDirectoryFileArray objectAtIndex:index]];
        NSUInteger pathSource[2] = {0, index};
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:pathSource length:2];

        [indexPaths addObject:path];
    }       
    index++;

}
}
```

Comment: but i didnt want to delet the row i want to share the row values to googledoc

Comment: Dude,it was for my case.Don't go onto the array name.
Just check the values returned is correct or not.

Comment: +1 for your answer,but still am struggling to get it.its my fault.

Comment: NSArray* toReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: indexPath, self.selectedIndexPath, nil];
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
Instead of these two lines replace the code which i have given in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.
Try activating the breakpoints and then check the values in array.

Comment: That is an array which consists the value of all the cell.Means it is the array using which you are populating the cells.

Comment: haii.[m_owner uploadString:path]; path undeclared

Comment: Dude,
your path should be a NSString variable.
So declare it as NSString*path,and give it the value on which you want to upload.